# Pure javascript and css splitter code using drag and drop, cursor issue

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop, cursor

Im trying to set the cursor abover my drop panel, but i got a flicker effect.

How i set the cursor for my example work ?

I try a lot of things to do this work.

Im using this code but i want to improve the visual of drag and drop.

I tried other events to make this sample work with right cursor and no one works fine, i changed the real function of position the splitter to on dragover event to work, because ondragenter not working.

```js
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function handleDragStart(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    //Seta as propriedades
    pEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    pEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", pTarget.id);
}

function handleDragOver(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    if (pEvent.preventDefault) { pEvent.preventDefault(); }

    pEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

    //Pega a referência dos componentes
    var ldivMain = document.getElementById('divMain');
    var ldivLeft = document.getElementById('divLeft');
    var ldivRight = document.getElementById('divRight');

    //Armazena a posição divSplitterV
    var lPosX = pEvent.clientX;
    var lSize_Max = ldivMain.clientWidth -12;
    var lSize_New = lSize_Max - lPosX;

    //See here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    //Not working got a flicker effect
    //ldivLeft.style.cursor = 'e-resize';
    //ldivRight.style.cursor = 'e-resize';

    //Ajusta o tamanho do painel
    ldivLeft.style.width = lPosX + 'px';
    //Verifica qual o lado foi redirecionado
    ldivRight.style.width = lSize_New + 'px';

    return false;
}

function handleDragLeave(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    //Remove a classe do item
    //pTarget.classList.remove('dragover');
}

function handleDrop(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    //Stops the browser from redirecting.
    if (pEvent.preventDefault) { pEvent.preventDefault(); }
    if (pEvent.stopPropagation) { pEvent.stopPropagation(); }

    //Return
    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    var ldivLeft = document.getElementById('divLeft');

    //Splitter vertical
    pTarget.style.left = ldivLeft.clientWidth + 'px';
}

//Splitter-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function SETSplitterPosition()
{
    var ldivLeft = document.getElementById('divLeft');
    var ldivSplitterV = document.getElementById('divSplitterV');

    //Splitter vertical
    ldivSplitterV.style.top = '60px';
    ldivSplitterV.style.bottom = '60px';
    ldivSplitterV.style.left = ldivLeft.clientWidth + 'px';
}

//Functions----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function SETLayoutSize()
{
    var ldivMain = document.getElementById('divMain');
    var ldivLeft = document.getElementById('divLeft');
    var ldivRight = document.getElementById('divRight');

    var lSize_Max = ldivMain.clientWidth -12;
    var lSize_Band = (lSize_Max / 2);

    ldivLeft.style.width = lSize_Band + 'px';
    ldivRight.style.width = lSize_Band + 'px';

    SETSplitterPosition();
}

//Load Events--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Body_OnLoad()
{
    SETLayoutSize();
}

function Body_OnResize()
{
    SETLayoutSize();
}
```

```css
body
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
div.main
{
    background-color: #000000; 
    position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; right: 0px; bottom: 10px; 
}
div.top
{
    background-color: #ffd700;
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 10px; height: 50px; 
}
div.left
{
    background-color: #424242;
    position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 0px; bottom: 60px; 

    border-right:solid 1px #ffd700;
}
div.right
{
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute; top: 60px; right: 10px; bottom: 60px; 

    border-left:solid 1px red;
}
div.bottom
{
    position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 10px; bottom: 0px; height: 50px; background-color: greenyellow;
}
/*--Splitter--*/
div.splitter_vertical
{
    background-color: #000000; cursor: e-resize;
    position: absolute; width: 2px; z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="Body_OnLoad()" onresize="Body_OnResize()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="divMain" class="main">
            <div class="top">

            </div>
            <div id="divLeft" class="left" ondragover="handleDragOver(event, this)" ondrop="handleDrop(event, this)" >

            </div>
            <div id="divSplitterV" class="splitter_vertical" draggable="true" ondragstart="handleDragStart(event, this)" ondragend="handleDragEnd(event, this)">

            </div>
            <div id="divRight" class="right" ondragover="handleDragOver(event, this)" ondrop="handleDrop(event, this)">

            </div>
            <div class="bottom">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a pseudo-element on `div.splitter_vertical`, which will make it wide enough to grab onto, but won't affect its appearance.

For example, this will let you grab the splitter between 10px to its left and 10px to its right:

```
div.splitter_vertical:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: -10px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```js
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function handleDragStart(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    //Seta as propriedades
    pEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    pEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", pTarget.id);
}

function handleDragOver(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    if (pEvent.preventDefault) { pEvent.preventDefault(); }

    pEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';

    //Pega a referência dos componentes
    var ldivMain = document.getElementById('divMain');
    var ldivLeft = document.getElementById('divLeft');
    var ldivRight = document.getElementById('divRight');

    //Armazena a posição divSplitterV
    var lPosX = pEvent.clientX;
    var lSize_Max = ldivMain.clientWidth -12;
    var lSize_New = lSize_Max - lPosX;

    //See here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    //Not working got a flicker effect
    //ldivLeft.style.cursor = 'e-resize';
    //ldivRight.style.cursor = 'e-resize';

    //Ajusta o tamanho do painel
    ldivLeft.style.width = lPosX + 'px';
    //Verifica qual o lado foi redirecionado
    ldivRight.style.width = lSize_New + 'px';

    return false;
}

function handleDragLeave(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    //Remove a classe do item
    //pTarget.classList.remove('dragover');
}

function handleDrop(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    //Stops the browser from redirecting.
    if (pEvent.preventDefault) { pEvent.preventDefault(); }
    if (pEvent.stopPropagation) { pEvent.stopPropagation(); }

    //Return
    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(pEvent, pTarget)
{
    var ldivLeft = document.getElementById('divLeft');

    //Splitter vertical
    pTarget.style.left = ldivLeft.clientWidth + 'px';
}

//Splitter-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function SETSplitterPosition()
{
    var ldivLeft = document.getElementById('divLeft');
    var ldivSplitterV = document.getElementById('divSplitterV');

    //Splitter vertical
    ldivSplitterV.style.top = '60px';
    ldivSplitterV.style.bottom = '60px';
    ldivSplitterV.style.left = ldivLeft.clientWidth + 'px';
}

//Functions----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function SETLayoutSize()
{
    var ldivMain = document.getElementById('divMain');
    var ldivLeft = document.getElementById('divLeft');
    var ldivRight = document.getElementById('divRight');

    var lSize_Max = ldivMain.clientWidth -12;
    var lSize_Band = (lSize_Max / 2);

    ldivLeft.style.width = lSize_Band + 'px';
    ldivRight.style.width = lSize_Band + 'px';

    SETSplitterPosition();
}

//Load Events--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function Body_OnLoad()
{
    SETLayoutSize();
}

function Body_OnResize()
{
    SETLayoutSize();
}
```

```css
body
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
div.main
{
    background-color: #000000; 
    position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 10px; right: 0px; bottom: 10px; 
}
div.top
{
    background-color: #ffd700;
    position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 10px; height: 50px; 
}
div.left
{
    background-color: #424242;
    position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 0px; bottom: 60px; 

    border-right:solid 1px #ffd700;
}
div.right
{
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute; top: 60px; right: 10px; bottom: 60px; 

    border-left:solid 1px red;
}
div.bottom
{
    position: absolute; left: 0px; right: 10px; bottom: 0px; height: 50px; background-color: greenyellow;
}
/*--Splitter--*/
div.splitter_vertical
{
    background-color: #000000; cursor: e-resize;
    position: absolute; width: 2px; z-index: 5;
}

div.splitter_vertical:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: -10px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body onload="Body_OnLoad()" onresize="Body_OnResize()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="divMain" class="main">
            <div class="top">

            </div>
            <div id="divLeft" class="left" ondragover="handleDragOver(event, this)" ondrop="handleDrop(event, this)" >

            </div>
            <div id="divSplitterV" class="splitter_vertical" draggable="true" ondragstart="handleDragStart(event, this)" ondragend="handleDragEnd(event, this)">

            </div>
            <div id="divRight" class="right" ondragover="handleDragOver(event, this)" ondrop="handleDrop(event, this)">

            </div>
            <div class="bottom">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see your change in code snippet, but the cursor still wrong.

And i not see any change with your css sugestion.

Thanks guy.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question.  My code should make it easier to grab the splitter, which I assumed was related to your flicker problem.

Comment: OK, my issue is with the mouse cursor, i want to see a e-resize cursor to make my splitter more beatiful. Perhaps my english cause your misunderstood i wrote all with out a google translate before post.

Comment: Understood.  Don't have time to answer now, so hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: Now i see the improve of your sugestion and is good, now is much more easy to start the drag operation, i will go implement your code in my main project. Thanks.